# How to create a different object that can be referenced globally in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm creating an API and I want to have a global object for logs. The idea is to log either success or failure for every request to the API, but avoid passing the logger object around, and not have one logger for each class along the way because you can't track which log goes to which request.

I originally created an object

```
object Logger {
    private var instance: LogEntry? = null
}
```

And I added functions to said object, so I can call them from anywhere. However, if I do that, the instance of the log might get changed by multiple requests. How can I make sure that every request has it's own log object that gets destroyed after every call?

Answer (score 0):

Not really Kotlin specific (and I'm more of a Java guy than Kotlin really), but this is a great case for [dependency injection](https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI).  Each request's constructor (or initialization) should allow a `logger` object to be passed in as a parameter.

This allows the framework to decide which kind of logger to pass in, and to manage the lifecycle of the logger.

The logger interface itself might be immutable so that clients can't change it once the framework initializes it.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea, but then I have to pass that logger object to all underlaying calls withing the service, polluting all calls with the same object.  I'm truing to avoid that

Comment: Not really -- if you use DI to inject those other object dependencies into your target, they'll be part of the same context, and it also externalizes the initialization of the dependent objects cleaning your business logic code up in the process.

Comment: I see this works the same as Spring, but my main problem is that I have a structure that looks like `Controller -> Service -> Provider -> Presenter`, so if I inject a logger on the `Controller`, how do I avoid passing that same logger object to the `Service`, to the `Provider` or the `Presenter`, but still able to log the errors per request and not per class?

Comment: I added the object using Spring's dependency injection and I ended up passing the logger object around as part of the context of the call. No other choice